# Where are URL-s stored on the Samfind bookmarks bar on OS X Snow Leopard?

Tags: firefox, osx-lion, bookmarks, firefox-extensions

Does anyone know where are URL-s stored on the "Samfind bookmarks bar" firefox extention on OS X Snow Leopard?

I need to find the specific file, as I can no longer boot up the hard disk that samfind ran on earlier, but I wouldn't like to loose my bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's stored as part of your Firefox profile in `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles`.

In that directory is a profile directory named e.g. `nhq878b7.default`.

The file containing the Samfind bookmarks is `samfindlayout.xml`. To improve your chances of restoring everything, just copy the entire directory and all its contents.

Comment: Oh man thank you so much. I really do wonder HOW you just knew that?! :)

Comment: @bencze I installed it and looked for it. Simple enough. You're welcome.